# How to assign variable to JSON in Django Views.py context

Tags: python, django

I'm Getting Data from an external API, in which i convert to JSON then i add the data in context to use in my Template. the problem is that the different variables in the API have a specific assigned number. i want to store that number in my database so i can assign them to specific objects on my website.

here is the code

```
models.py =

class Coin(models.Model):
   collection_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
   null=True,)
   artist_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, 
   null=True,)
   api_text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, 
   null=True,)
   date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   def __str__(self):
    return self.collection_name

   class Meta:
    ordering = ['-date_posted',]

Views.py

def projectdetails(request, pk):
    url = 'XXX'
    parameters = {
        'slug': 'bitcoin',
        'convert': 'USD',
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXX'
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    api_price = response.json()
    coin = Coin.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'coin':coin,
        'gimmeprice':api_price['data']['1']['quote']['USD']['price'],
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/project_details_coin.html', context)
```

the [1] in the context is where i want to use a variable that i assign to "api_text"

im having troubles figuring out with Django Model Query to use and how

what i've tried

```
def projectdetailscoins(request, pk):
    url = 'XXX'
    parameters = {
        'slug': 'bitcoin',
        'convert': 'USD',
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'XXX'
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    api_price = response.json()
    coin = Coin.objects.get(id=pk)
    api_data = Coin.api_text_2_coin
    notifications = Notification.objects.all()
    context = {'coin':coin, 'notifications':notifications,
        'gimmeprice':api_price['data'][api_data]['quote']['USD']['price'],
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/project_details_coin.html', context)
```

but still no success? is it even possible to use a variable name in a JSON response like i did with the [api_data]???

Here is my template file

```
 {% if coin.price != None %}
                                        <div class="bid-main">
                                            <p class="bid body-mb">Current Price</p>
                                            <h3 class="heading-h3 bid-head">$
                                              {{gimmeprice}}
                                              {{coin.price_currency_name}}</h3>
                                        </div>
                                        {% endif %}
```

and here is the API data in JSON. keep in mind that im successful at getting the price so it has nothing to do with the API or the API call

```
{'data': {'9436': {'circulating_supply': 553015035249169.75,
                   'cmc_rank': 130,
                   'date_added': '2021-04-23T00:00:00.000Z',
                   'id': 9436,
                   'is_active': 1,
                   'is_fiat': 0,
                   'last_updated': '2022-03-01T22:32:00.000Z',
                   'max_supply': 1000000000000000,
                   'name': 'Dogelon Mars',
                   'num_market_pairs': 38,
                   'platform': {'id': 1027,
                                'name': 'Ethereum',
                                'slug': 'ethereum',
                                'symbol': 'ETH',
                                'token_address': '0x761d38e5ddf6ccf6cf7c55759d5210750b5d60f3'},
                   'quote': {'USD': {'fully_diluted_market_cap': 850140803.24,
                                     'last_updated': '2022-03-01T22:32:00.000Z',
                                     'market_cap': 470140646.2727168,
                                     'market_cap_dominance': 0.0243,
                                     'percent_change_1h': 0.01660678,
                                     'percent_change_24h': 5.52791865,
                                     'percent_change_30d': -0.5865211,
                                     'percent_change_60d': -44.69641882,
                                     'percent_change_7d': 9.09212527,
                                     'percent_change_90d': -44.69817199,
                                     'price': 8.501408032439614e-07,
                                     'volume_24h': 12527356.35523997,
                                     'volume_change_24h': 7.0812}},
                   'self_reported_circulating_supply': None,
                   'self_reported_market_cap': None,
                   'slug': 'dogelon',
                   'symbol': 'ELON',
                   'tags': [{'category': 'PROPERTY',
                             'name': 'Memes',
                             'slug': 'memes'},
                            {'category': 'PROPERTY',
                             'name': 'Payments',
                             'slug': 'payments'},
                            {'category': 'PROPERTY',
                             'name': 'Polygon Ecosystem',
                             'slug': 'polygon-ecosystem'},
                            {'category': 'PROPERTY',
                             'name': 'Doggone Doggerel',
                             'slug': 'doggone-doggerel'}],
                   'total_supply': 1000000000000000}},
 'status': {'credit_count': 1,
            'elapsed': 35,
            'error_code': 0,
            'error_message': None,
            'notice': None,
            'timestamp': '2022-03-01T22:34:04.646Z'}}
```

**CONCLUSION!! WE DID IT GUYS!!**
your answers made me realize that api_text was providing data that was not in the API call, which made me realize that the problem was in the PARAMETER, my dumb ass had
parameters = {
'slug': 'bitcoin',
'convert': 'USD',
}
instead of

parameters = {
'slug': coin.api_slug,
'convert': 'USD',
}

Comment: Can you post your whole model code. It's kinda hard to understand what attribute to put there if we don't know how is the data modeled.

Comment: ok i'll add the whole thing in a few mins, please let me know if you can think of something because adding the variable name in context keeps giving errors

Comment: It is possible to use a variable name when accessing Python dicts like you are in the example. I don't see why `api_price['data'][coin.api_text]['qoute']['USD']['price']` would not work. How are you setting the `api_text`? That could be the issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer i appreciate it, i just added the template file so you can see how i use it, and this is the error i keep getting, <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000001FF5E263520>

Comment: "_but still no success?_" Please be more clear: what is not working? What error / result do you get? How does the data you get in the response look like? Please see [ask] and how to write a [mre].

Comment: Are you using model instance or model class? If you are using `Coin.api_text` this is completely wrong. You need to use `coin.api_text`. You already retrieve the model instance using the get query. This error might be if you are passing the Coin class instead of the instance.

Comment: when i use the instance, i get another error.....Exception type: KeyError , Exception Value: '74'

Comment: @abdulAzizBarkat the data is a string displaying numbers just like the rest of the dictionary

Comment: @vinkomlacic the "exception value" in the error is the data in the api_text so i have to figure out what the KeyError is

Comment: I suggest using the instance and `str(coin.api_text)` to make sure you use the string. If that doesn't work try `int(coin.api_text)`. If nothing works, having an example of the `api_price` data structure would help immensely. In any case, you definitely don't want to go with the class option.

Comment: @vinkomlacic i just added the api_price data in the question, when i run the code to get the price in the API, everything is working. but the errors is strictly from the api_text object,  let me know what you think. and i'll probably have to make a new posts with as much code as possible, its a big project so i have a lot of code but ill try to add enough for people to get a better angle of the problem.

Comment: Can you debug or print the value of `coin.api_price` and let me know what is the value and type you get there?

Comment: A KeyError means the key you give does not exist in the dictionary, i.e. `coin.api_text` which is `74` according to your error (which you have _yet_ to add to your question...),  simply does not exist in the response you got from the API.

Comment: your answers made me realize that api_text was providing data that was not in the API call, which made me realize that the problem was in the PARAMETER, the slug was linking to bitcoin the whole time, thats why '74' and other api_text data wasn't being found. check in the answer for the update. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was in the PARAMETER, i had

```
parameters = { 'slug': 'bitcoin', 'convert': 'USD', }
```

instead of

```
parameters = { 'slug': coin.api_slug, 'convert': 'USD', }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:

Views.py

```
def projectdetails(request, pk):
    url = 'XXX'
    parameters = {
        'slug': 'bitcoin',
        'convert': 'USD',
    }
    headers = {
        'Accepts': 'application/json',
        'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': 'XXX'
    }
    session = Session()
    session.headers.update(headers)
    response = session.get(url, params=parameters)
    api_price = response.json()
    coin = Coin.objects.get(id=pk)
    api_data = coin.api_text

    context = {'coin':coin,
        'gimmeprice':api_price['data'][api_data]['quote']['USD']['price'],
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/project_details_coin.html', context)
```

Comment: sorry maybe I didn't explain correctly, i'm not trying to save it to my database, im trying to use the saved data in my database that are in "api_text" and put it where the [1] is.......EXP: 'gimmeprice':api_price['data'][api_data]['quote']['USD']['price'],

Comment: okay, let me post again...

Comment: didn't realized you already edited it.....i tried that before and i tried it again with yours and i keep getting error "KeyError: '74'"

Comment: actually the error is KeyError: <django.db.models.query_utils.DeferredAttribute object at 0x000002601E703520>